# Django authentication problem with mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am working on a Django project which uses Mysql database to manage user authentication and I also developed a custom user model with the AbstractBaseUser class
I can migrate the table in the database and insert a user to the database by using the createsuperuser function and everything is ok but when I try to authenticate the mentioned user, the authenticate function returns None.
The strange thing is that when I use default Myadmin db.sqlite3 database service of Django, authenticate function works correctly and returns the user

```
    username = 'p'
    password = 'p'
    user = authenticate(request , username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        return HttpResponse('the user exist')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('the user does not exist in database')
```

i also checked the charset of the columns in the database and it was utf8mb4_general_ci

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few things you can check and troubleshoot:

**Database Configuration:** Make sure your MySQL database settings in your Django project's settings.py file are correctly configured. Ensure that the ENGINE, NAME, USER, PASSWORD, and other necessary settings are accurate and match the MySQL database you are using.

**Custom User Model:** Since you are using a custom user model based on AbstractBaseUser, ensure that your custom user model is properly defined and configured. It should include the required fields such as email and password and override necessary methods for authentication to work correctly.

**Hashing Algorithm:** Django uses a password hashing algorithm to store and check passwords. Ensure that the AUTH_PASSWORD_HASHERS setting in your settings.py file is correctly configured. It should typically include 'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher' or 'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher'.

**Authentication Backend:** Check that the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting in your settings.py includes 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'. This is the default authentication backend that works with custom user models.

**Database Collation and Charset:** You've mentioned that you've checked the charset of the columns in the database and it's utf8mb4_general_ci. Make sure that the charset and collation settings are consistent across your database, tables, and columns. If you are using a custom collation, ensure that it's appropriate for storing passwords.

**Password Hash Compatibility:** If you migrated user data from SQLite to MySQL, make sure that the password hashes have been transferred correctly. Django uses different password hashers for different databases, and it's important that the password hashes are compatible with the hashers used by MySQL.

Comment: Thank you , My Database Configuration and connection are correct because I can insert a user row to my user table with createsuperuser function ,
Also my custom user model works correctly because It works with Django default sqllite database
I have also added 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'. in my setting.py file

But i don't know what should i do with Password Hashing Compatibility and Database Collation and Charset